# Discord OAuth with Expo: Something went wrong trying to finish signing in

Tags: typescript, react-native, oauth-2.0, expo, expo-auth-session

I'm trying to use the OAuth Discord authentication with expo and I got the following error due to clicking on authorize

[auth authorization screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tBTzR.png)
[auth error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFwr3.png)

I'm using the following code:

```
const discovery = {
    authorizationEndpoint: "https://discord.com/oauth2/authorize",
  };

  const [request, response, promptAsync] = useAuthRequest(
    {
      responseType: RESPONSE_TYPE,
      clientId: CLIENT_ID,
      scopes: SCOPE,
      redirectUri: REDIRECT_URI
    },
    discovery
  );

  const signIn = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await promptAsync();
      if (response?.type === "success") {
        console.log("TOKEN -------->" + response.params);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("ERRO NO TOKEN -------->");
      alert(error);
    } finally {
      console.log("CHAMADA FINALIZADA -------->");
      console.log(response)
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };
```

I tried using the `makeRedirectUri()` method, but the only way that worked for me was registering the app on expo.dev and setting the redirectUri directly with the format: `'https://auth.expo.io/@<username >/<project_name>'` .

I suspect it might have something to do with the environment, but I couldn't find anything about it.